# ASP.Net MVC 3 Multiple CheckBoxLists

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel, checkboxlist, mvc-editor-templates

I am developing an ASP.Net MVC 3 Web application and I recently posted a question about how to display a checkboxlist

[ASP.Net MVC 3 Retrieve Checkbox List Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9973977/asp-net-mvc-3-retrieve-checkbox-list-values)

and thanks to the help from RubbleFord and Darin Dimitrov I was able to get this working.

This works nicely for one checkboxlist, however, I now need to be able to display several checkboxlists on the same View, ie, see image attached.

[image]

The ViewModels I use to currently display one list are as follows;

```
public class ViewModelShiftSubSpecialties
{

    public ListItem specialtyName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ViewModelCheckBox> SubSpecialityList { get; set; }

}

public class ViewModelCheckBox
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
}
```

And within my Controller I populate ViewModelShiftSubSpecialties like so:

```
var subSpecialties = GetSubSpecialtiesForSpecialty(5);

        ViewModelShiftSubSpecialties viewModel = new ViewModelShiftSubSpecialties();

        var checkBoxList = new List<ViewModelCheckBox>();

        viewModel.specialtyName = _listService.GetListItemByID(5); //Medicine Specialty

        foreach (var item in subSpecialties)
        {
            ViewModelCheckBox chkBox = new ViewModelCheckBox { Id = item.subID.ToString(), Name = item.ListSub.description, Checked = false };
            checkBoxList.Add(chkBox);
        }

        viewModel.SubSpecialityList = checkBoxList;
```

In my View, I display the list name and also use an Editor template to display the checkboxlist

```
<h3>@Model.specialtyName.description</h3>
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.SubSpecialityList)
```

However, I am totally stumped as how to get the above code to work with multiple checkboxlists on one View. Is this even possible?

I would really appreciate if someone could please help me with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you've done all the work already. You already have an Editor Template that works correctly with a ViewModelCheckBox IEnumerable. Editor templates wouldn't be useful if you couldn't reuse them for the same datatype. You just need to use it three times. Just extend your ViewModel

```
public class ViewModelShiftSubSpecialties
{
    public ListItem specialtyName { get; set; } //Might need 3 of these
    public IEnumerable<ViewModelCheckBox> SubSpecialityList1 { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ViewModelCheckBox> SubSpecialityList2 { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ViewModelCheckBox> SubSpecialityList3 { get; set; }
}
```

Create all three in your controller (and give them better names then I did).

And then in your View

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.SubSpecialityList1)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.SubSpecialityList2)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.SubSpecialityList3)
```

Alternatively you could create a class that contains a single specialty name and `IEnumerable ViewModelCheckBox`, and have your ViewModel have an IEnumerable of this new class. Then create a new Editor Template for this new class. I think this is worth it if your list size is variable/ might change. Otherwise I'd use the earlier solution for a simple fix.

```
public class ViewModelShiftSubSpecialties
{
    public class IEnumerable<SubSpecialty> { get; set; }
}

public class SubSpecialty
{
    public ListItem specialtyName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ViewModelCheckBox> SubSpecialityList
}
```

Comment: This looks good, thanks. Could you elaborate a bit more of your 2nd solution? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for this AFinkelstein - this is really useful.