# How do I get the selected values of a checkbox list?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkboxlist

If I have a CheckBoxList within a form, like this...

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Product", FormMethod.Post))
{
    ...

    @Html.CheckBoxList("Categories", Model.AllCategories);

    ...
}
```

... how can I get a list of selected values (checked values) in my controller action?

For example, if the check box list has items with values of:

> Cat. 1
>
> Cat. 2
>
> Cat. 3
>
> Cat. 4

...and `Cat. 2` and `Cat. 3` are selected, how can I get an array containing those values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the simplest case, the controller action should look like this (in the Product controller):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(string[] Categories)
{
    // Process selected checkbox values here, using the Categories array
    ...
}
```

In a more complex case (with more form fields), it may be better to use a view model, and add a Categories property to it.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    ...

    public string[] Categories { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(MyViewModel model)
{
    // Process selected checkbox values here, using the model.Categories array
    ...
}
```

Simple Q & A, but hopefully it will help someone looking for the answer (like I was, when I first started learning ASP.NET MVC).

P.S.  If you've got something better or more detailed, please post it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the answer for this question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9973977/asp-net-mvc-3-retrieve-checkbox-list-values)  I use this all the time and it works perfectly.